# Handlebars display list of strings from object

Tags: javascript, c#, handlebars.js

Trying to display list of strings inside the template after retrieving data as JSON.

```
 public class AutoCompSearchResult
  {
    public List<string> eventName = new List<string>();    
  }
```

The problem is that I need to display one by one on the list, but it displays all list between

```
<li> tags:
<li>EVENTS</li>
{{#each this}}
<li style="list-style: none">{{eventName}} -- </li>
{{/each}}
```

I have tried similar solutions https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content
but this does not output the data for my case since, I do not know the syntax for handlebars js using:

```
{{#each eventName}}
<li style="list-style: none">{{this}} -- </li>
{{/each}}
```

I want final result to be:

```
<ul>
 <li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Chrome console of data passed:
eventName

```
[Object
    eventName:Array[2]
    0:"Dr. Dog"
    1:"Laura Gibson"
    __proto__
    :
    Array[0]
    __proto__
    :
    Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out:

```
    <ul>
        <li>EVENTS</li>
        {{#each this.[0].eventName}}
        <li style="list-style: none">{{this}} -- </li>
        {{/each}}
```

I had to use this.[0] to access the object and then iterate over member variable: eventName